# Book recommendation treewidth

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am searching for a good book (or survey paper) on treewidth. I would be delighted if the book/paper surveys multiple approaches to treewidth (eg: structural, algorithmic, `language-theoretic') and also discusses on treewidth in isolation.

The book I found is *Treewidth: Computations and Approximations*, by Ton Kloks. This book approaches treewidth from a structural point of view (partial $k$-tree, chordal completion) and also algorithmic point of view. It covers treewidth computation and approximation in special graph classes, and talks about treewidth bounded graphs.

*Is this book a must-read?* Or is there any other choice out there?

I liked the game theoretic definition of treewidth in the survey *Practical algorithms for MSO model-checking on tree-decomposable graphs*, Langer et. al. It is equivalent to the traditional tree-decomposition based definition in a natural way (As a sidenote, now there is a game theoretic approach to MSO model checking).

**Could you point out a book/paper on treewidth that keeps multiple appraches to it in mind?**

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I stumbled on the paper *A tourist guide through treewidth* again. This is worth cosidering I guess.

Comment: I highly recommend Bruce Reed's chapter on treewidth in a book. See link below.
 
https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/surveys-in-combinatorics-1997/tree-width-and-tangles-a-new-connectivity-measure-and-some-applications/50B61BC367CC21EA85F02038F3CC632D

Comment: Martin Grohe's article on tangles is another related article though I have not yet read it yet. Tangles and Connectivity in Graphs. https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04727

Comment: Another candidate: *Treewidth: Characterizations, Applications, and Computations* by Bodlaender

Comment: Yet another: *Tree Decompositions, Treewidth, and NP-Hard Problems*, by Voigt