# Can someone recommend a reference on graph minors structure theorem and sublinear treewidth?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, treewidth

Can someone recommend a reference on graph minors structure theorem and sublinear treewidth?  Doesn't have to be the newest/strongest results as long as it's easier than tracking down all the papers written about these results.

Mostly I'm interested in finding the details about the existence of large grid minors in large treewidth planar and minor free graphs and sublinear treewidth of planar and minor free graphs from basic graph theory.

Comment: The book http://parameterized-algorithms.mimuw.edu.pl/parameterized-algorithms.pdf chapter 7.7

Comment: @Laakeri I meant covering the proof of sublinear treewidth

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "proof" of sub-linear treewidth? It is an easy consequence of separator theorems for planar graphs and more generally minor free graphs.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri  I guess I mean from reasonably basic graph theory basically anything that's easier than tracking down all the related papers

Comment: You may  find some references here useful. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/44317/book-recommendation-treewidth